# get anchor tag id in jquery

Tags: jquery, anchor

i have an anchor tag like this

```
<div id="'+itemArr[0]+'">'+itemArr[1]+' 
<a id="'+itemArr[0]+'" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:chatWith('+rep+')"  disabled="true">Chat</a> 
 <a  href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:changeActive('+value+');" disabled="true">Active</a><br> </div>'
```

how can i enable or disable that particular anchor tag can you please guide me

Thanks for advance.

Comment: How is this related to `PHP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
  var disabled = $(this).attr('disabled');
  // checking that disabled exists or not
  // as I bind click to all anchor tags
  if( typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false ) {
      $(this).attr('disabled', disabled == 'true' ? 'false' : 'true');
  }
});
```

Another way:

```
$('a[disabled]').on('click', function() {
  this.disabled = this.disabled == 'true' ? 'false' : 'true';
});
```

#### According to comment

Try this:

```
<a  href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:changeActive(this, 'value');" disabled="true">Active</a>

<script>
    function changeActive(el, val) {
       var disabled = el.getAttribute('disabled');

       if( typeof disabled !== 'undefined' && disabled != null ) {
          el.setAttribute('disabled', disabled == 'true' ? 'false' : 'true');
       }
    }
</script>
```

***[​Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/cvfvS/2/)***

Comment: Do anchor elements even have a disabled property?

Comment: hey thecodeparadox thanks for response how can i do this when i click changeActive() in another function

Comment: Oh I see OP is using a custom attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$(this).attr("id");
```

Or in the traditional JavaScript way,

```
this.getAttribute('id');
```

Comment: Even though your answer answers the title, it doesn't answer the question (if there is a question).